# MVC jqgrid Page Navigation When Data is Sorted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, paging

I am running a code with ASP .NET MVC jqgrid that populates the grid with data from the database.
The code is taken from : 
http://jetmathew.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/asp-net-mvc-2-with-entity-framework-json-jquery-and-jqgrid/

The problem is that when I go to second page and sort the data with any column. It sorts the whole data but takes me to 1st page.
I want to remain on second page with whole sorted data. Is this a bug? And is there anyway around to get things go my way?

The sane thing is happening on all examples on this link as well.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. Think about it, what meaning does the pagenumber have when the sortcolumn changes? IMHO  none since you are looking at a different dataset...
What are you trying to achieve here?

*edit*

Craig Stuntz added Jquery BBQ integration to Jqgrid. This enables url history to jqgrid.
Using this you can take the current page from the querystring.

http://craigstuntz.github.com/jqGrid/

I still stand by my original answer though :)

/Daddy

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are saying but the thing is other libraries like SlickGrid and FlexGrid provide the sort feature without navigating to the first page. But the whole dataset is sorted. Forexample, if I am on the 400th page and I sort, why should I go to the first page and then go back again to 400th page.

Comment: And can you tell me whether I can pass an extra parameter from the view e.g. the page number and access that extra parameter in the controller in function e.g. public ActionResult LinqGridData
    (string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows) and How can I do that?